# DDMS is not showing expected output when dumping HPROF file

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

I am trying to use the DDMS in android to see how much memory my app is using but I can't seem to get it to show anything readable. I press dump the HPROF file and all I get is gibberish:
[image]

This used to work, but stopped ever since I switched workspaces(old one was corrupt) in eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after reading this [Memory Analysis for Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html) I realized that when I re-installed eclipse I forgot to re-install MAT. So now everything works as it should