# Error using DDMS in eclipse after switching workspaces

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, ddms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DDMS is not showing expected output when dumping HPROF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114935/ddms-is-not-showing-expected-output-when-dumping-hprof-file)

I am trying to use the DDMS in android to see how much memory my app is using but I can't seem to get it to show anything readable. I press dump the HPROF file and all I get is gibberish:
[image]

This used to work, but stopped ever since I switched workspaces(old one was corrupt) in eclipse. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the ADT plugin, but the same thing happened. Any Ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after reading this http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html I realized that when I re-installed eclipse I forgot to re-install MAT. So now everything works as it should